# Exclude custom MSBuild information from csproj file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have included custom code into csproj file which Zip the whole project on build. I would like to exclude my custom MSBuild code from csproj file while zipping. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call your zipping target directly when running your csproj

```
msbuild your.csproj /target:yourZipTarget
```

If you need to control zipping/not-zipping for normal builds you could add a [condition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7szfhaft.aspx) to your zipping target

```
<Target Name="yourZipTarget" Condition="'$(Configuration)'!='DEBUG'">
    <!-- zipping... -->
</Target>
```

The example above would run the zipping only when doing a RELEASE build (unless you didn't introduce another custom Configuration).

You could declare your own project level property for your zipping Condition and specify (and override a default value) it when calling msbuild

`msbuild your.csproj /property:DoZip=true`

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DoZip Condition=" '$(DoZip)' == '' ">false</DoZip>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="yourZipTarget" Condition="'$(DoZip)'!='false'">
    <!-- zipping... -->
</Target>
```

Comment: Should be $(Configuration) instead of $(CONFIG)

Comment: @Tomas You're right. I corrected the example (which I copied from one of my custom build scripts) accordingly.

Comment: @Tomas You're right. I corrected the example (which I copied from one of my custom build scripts) accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's a few options

1 - move your custom zip code out of the project

2 - you own the zip code so alter it

3 - use the  msbuild syntax to exclude files from an ItemGroup

It's hard to say what the best solution for you is without seeing the MSBuild project file and understanding what you mean by "i've added custom code into csproj file".